# Having issues in handling keydown events while working with nested contenteditable divs

Tags: html, vue.js, event-handling, vuejs3, contenteditable

I am making cms, most of the rules and pattern is copied from notion.so's coding style.

RenderBlock.vue component:

```
<template>
    <BlockRenderHeadings 
        v-if="
            state.blockType === 'heading_1' 
            || state.blockType === 'heading_2' 
            || state.blockType === 'heading_3'
        "
        :treeId="props.treeId"
        :blockId="props.blockId"
        @keydown="propogateKeyUp"
    >
    </BlockRenderHeadings>

    <BlockRenderCheckboxes
        v-else-if="state.blockType === 'checkbox'"
        :treeId="props.treeId"
        :blockId="props.blockId"
        @keydown="propogateKeyUp"
    ></BlockRenderCheckboxes>

    <BlockRenderParagraph
        v-else-if="state.blockType === 'paragraph'"
        :treeId="props.treeId"
        :blockId="props.blockId"
        @keydown="propogateKeyUp($event)"
        class="xdoc-rich-text"
    ></BlockRenderParagraph>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps, defineEmits, onMounted, reactive, computed } from 'vue';
import BlockRenderHeadings from './BlockRenderHeadings.vue';
import BlockRenderCheckboxes from './BlockRenderCheckboxes.vue';
import BlockRenderParagraph from './BlockRenderParagraph.vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';

const emits = defineEmits([
    'propogateKeyUp'
])

const props = defineProps({
    blockId: String,
    treeId: String
})

const state = reactive({
    blockType: 0,
})

const store = useStore()

const blockDataInStore = computed(() => store.getters['blocks/getBlockData'](props.blockId))

onMounted(() => {
    state.blockType = blockDataInStore.value.type
    getChildBlocksData()    
})

function getChildBlocksData() {
    let childBlocksIds = blockDataInStore.value.children

    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (childBlocksIds[0] === null) {
            resolve()
        }
        else {
            Promise.all([
                ...childBlocksIds.map(blockId => {
                    return store.dispatch('blocks/fetchBlockData', {
                        blockId
                    })
                })
            ])
            .then(() => {
                resolve()
            })
            .catch(() => reject())
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        for(let i = 0; i!==childBlocksIds.length; i++) {
            store.dispatch('trees/addChild', {
                treeId: props.treeId,
                parentBlockId: props.blockId,
                childBlockId: childBlocksIds[i]
            })
        }
    })
}

    
//handles key up events for `slash` to allow user to append block
function propogateKeyUp(e, defaultBlockId = "1") {    
    console.log(e.key)
    if (['Enter', '/', 'Backspace', 'Escape'].includes(e.key)) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {
            if (!e.__customEventData) e.__customEventData = {}
            e.__customEventData.defaultBlockId = defaultBlockId
        }

        emits('propogateKeyUp', e)
    }
}
</script>
```

RenderPage.vue component:

```
<template>
    <div 
        contenteditable="true"
        data-contenteditable-root="true" 
        :data-block-id="pageId"
    >
        <main>
            <template v-if="childBlocksInStore?.length && childBlocksInStore[0] !== null">
                <template v-for="block in childBlocksInStore" :key="block.id">
                    <RenderBlock
                        :treeId="pageId"
                        :blockId="block.id.toString()"
                        @propogateKeyUp="handleKeyUp"
                    ></RenderBlock>
                </template>
            </template>


            <div 
                v-else
                contenteditable="true"
                placeholder='Press "/" for commands'
                @keydown="handleKeyUp"
            >
            </div>

            <BaseMenu
                v-show="state.menuVisibility"
                :pos="state.menuPos"
                @handleSelection="appendNewBlock($event.selectedBlockTypeId)"
            ></BaseMenu>
        </main>
    </div>
        
</template>

<script setup>

import { onMounted, onUnmounted, inject, watch, reactive, defineProps, computed } from 'vue';
import RenderBlock from './RenderBlock.vue';
import BaseMenu from './BaseMenu.vue';
import { useStore } from 'vuex';
import Paragraph from '@/models/blocks/Paragraph';

const state = reactive({
    menuVisibility: false,
    menuOpenForBlockId: '',
    menuOpenForEle: '',
    menuPos: {x: '', y: '', spaceAdjustment: ''}
})

let pageId = inject("blockId")

const props = defineProps({
    pageDataRaw: Object
})


const store = useStore()

watch(pageId, (newVal, oldVal) => {
    if (newVal !== oldVal) {
        store.commit('trees/setNewTree', {
            treeId: pageId.value
        })
        getChildBlocksData()
    }
})

onMounted(() => {
    store.commit('trees/setNewTree', {
        treeId: pageId.value
    })
    getChildBlocksData()

    document.addEventListener('mouseup', getTextSelectionFromMouse);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', getTextSelectionFromKeyBoard);
})

onUnmounted(() => {
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', getTextSelectionFromMouse);
    document.removeEventListener('keyup', getTextSelectionFromKeyBoard);
});

const childBlocksInStore = computed(() => store.getters['trees/getNode'](pageId.value, pageId.value).children)

// getting data of children blocks if any
function getChildBlocksData() {
    const childBlocksIds = props.pageDataRaw.children

    new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        if (childBlocksIds[0] === null) {
            resolve()
        }
        else {
            Promise.all([
                ...childBlocksIds.map(blockId => {
                    return store.dispatch('blocks/fetchBlockData', {
                        blockId
                    })
                })
            ])
            .then(() => {
                resolve()
            })
            .catch(() => reject())
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        for(let i = 0; i!==childBlocksIds.length; i++) {
            store.dispatch('trees/addChild', {
                treeId: pageId.value,
                parentBlockId: pageId.value,
                childBlockId: childBlocksIds[i]
            })
        }
    })
}


function getTextSelectionFromMouse() {
    const selection = window.getSelection()

    if (selection.isCollapsed === true && selection.type !== 'Range') return;
    
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0)

    const startContainer = range.startContainer.parentNode
    const endContainer = range.endContainer.parentNode

    console.log(startContainer, endContainer)
}


function getTextSelectionFromKeyBoard() {
    const selection = window.getSelection();

    if (selection.type !== 'Range') return;

    console.log(selection.toString())
}

function setMenuPosition(target, fromStart = true) {
    const selection = window.getSelection();
    
    let y;
    if (selection.rangeCount !== 0) {
      const range = selection.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
      range.collapse(fromStart);
      const rect = range.getClientRects()[0];
      if (rect) {
        state.menuPos.spaceAdjustment = "+ 1.5"
        state.menuPos.x = rect.left;
        y = rect.top;
      }
    }

    const keyPressPosition = target.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
    const menuHeight = 100;
    const viewportHeight = window.innerHeight;

    if (viewportHeight - keyPressPosition < menuHeight + 100) {
        state.menuPos.spaceAdjustment = "- 0.5"
        y -= menuHeight
    }

    state.menuPos.y = y
}

//handles key up events for `slash` to allow user to append block
let slashPressed = false
// let keystrokeSeq = ""
function handleKeyUp(e) {
    // if (slashPressed === true) {
    //     keystrokeSeq += e.key
    // }

    switch(e.key) {
        case 'Enter': {      
            e.preventDefault();
            
            if (slashPressed === false) {
                appendNewBlock(e.__customEventData.defaultBlockId)
            }
            else {
                // store.commit('blocks/removeCommandFromBlock', {
                //     blockId: state.menuOpenForBlockId,
                //     length: keystrokeSeq + 1 //+1 for slash
                // })
                // keystrokeSeq = ""
                
                console.log("creating slected block")
            }
            break
        }
        case '/': {
            setMenuPosition(e.target)
            slashPressed = true
            state.menuVisibility = true
            state.menuOpenForEle = e.target
            state.menuOpenForBlockId = e.target.getAttribute('data-block-id')
            break
        }
        case 'Escape': {
            slashPressed = false
            state.menuVisibility = false
            state.menuOpenForEle = ''
            state.menuOpenForBlockId = ''
            break
        }
        case 'Backspace': {
            if (slashPressed === false) {
                console.log("check if block has content if not delete the entire block")
            }
            break
        }
        default: {
            slashPressed = false
            state.menuOpenForBlockId = ''
            state.menuOpenForEle = ''
            state.menuVisibility = false
        }
    }
}

//append block to parentBlock
function appendNewBlock(selectedBlockTypeId) {
    let blockData;
    switch(selectedBlockTypeId) {
        case "1": {
            blockData = new Paragraph({})
        }
        // case "2": {
        //     blockData = new CheckBox({})
        // }
        // case "3": {
        //     blockData = new List({})
        // }
    }
    store.dispatch('trees/addChild', {
        treeId: pageId.value,
        parentBlockId: state.menuOpenForBlockId,
        childBlockId: blockData.id,
        setFocusOnCreatedBlock: true
    })

    store.commit('blocks/setBlockData', {
        data: blockData
    })
    
    state.menuVisibility = false
    slashPressed = false
    state.menuOpenForBlockId = ''
    state.menuOpenForEle = ''
}
</script>
```

RenderParagraph.vue component

```
<template>
    <div
        :data-block-id="props.blockId"      
        placeholder='Press "/" for commands'
    >
        <div v-if="blockDataInStore?.length" 
            style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; min-height: 1em;"
        >
            <template v-for="(richText, index) in blockDataInStore" :key="index">
                <BlockRenderRichText
                    :richText="richText"
                    :blockId="props.blockId.toString()"
                    data-contenteditable-leaf="true"
                    contenteditable="true"
                ></BlockRenderRichText>
            </template>
        </div>

        <template
            v-if="childBlocksInStore?.length && childBlocksInStore?.[0] !== null"
        >
            <RenderBlock v-for="block in childBlocksInStore"
                :treeId="props.treeId"
                :blockId="block.id.toString()"
                @propogateKeyUp="propogateKeyUp($event)"
                :key="block.id"
                style="margin-left: 12px;"
            ></RenderBlock>
        </template>
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { defineProps, computed, defineEmits } from 'vue'
import { useStore } from 'vuex'
import BlockRenderRichText from './BlockRenderRichText.vue'
import RenderBlock from './RenderBlock.vue'

const props = defineProps({
    treeId: String,
    blockId: String,
})

const emits = defineEmits([
    'propogateKeyUp'
])

const store = useStore()
const blockDataInStore = computed(() => store.getters['blocks/getBlockData'](props.blockId).paragraph.rich_text)
const childBlocksInStore = computed(() => store.getters['trees/getNode'](props.treeId, props.blockId).children)

//handles key up events for `slash` to allow user to append block
function propogateKeyUp(e, defaultBlockId = "1") {
    if (['Enter', '/', 'Backspace', 'Escape'].includes(e.key)) {
        if (e.key === 'Enter') {            
            if (!e.__customEventData) e.__customEventData = {}
            e.__customEventData.defaultBlockId = defaultBlockId
        }

        emits('propogateKeyUp', e)
    }
}
</script>
```

RenderRichText.vue component

```
<template>
    <div
        :style="annotations"
    >
        {{ text }}
    </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref, defineProps, onMounted } from "vue"

    const props = defineProps({
        richText: Object,
        blockId: String
    })

    let text = ref('')
    let annotations = ref({})
    
    onMounted(() => {
        text.value = props.richText.content

        const {bold, underline, strikethrough, italic, color} = props.richText.annotations
        
        let style = ''
        if(bold === true) style += 'font-weight: bold; '
        else style += 'font-weight: inherit; '

        if(underline === true) style += 'text-decoration: underline; '
        if(strikethrough === true) style += 'text-decoration: line-through; '
        if(italic === true) style += ' font-style: italic;'
        if(color !== '') style += ` color: ${color};`

        annotations.value = style
    })

</script>
```

I am not able to listen to keydown event on actual children div (specified by css-class: "xdoc-rich-text") when the parent div (root div of RenderPage.vue component) is made contenteditable. otherwise it works completely fine.

Comment: show BlockRenderParagraph.vue

Comment: I have added all necessary code, All data in vuex store is proper, and all getters setters in components are working fine.